HTTPX failing with Kraken API, albeit requests working
Running code with Python's requests library works. The equivalent with httpx keeps giving EAPI: Invalid Key. I've tried different things but can't figure out the issue. Body and headers provided are IDENTICAL in both cases and I run the examples in different occasions so nonce & signature are up-to-date.
Example code:
response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=data)  # WORKS
response = httpx.post(url, headers=headers, data=data)     # FAILS

Headers and bodies as examined:
    # REQUESTS REQUEST
    HEADERS: 
    {
        'User-Agent': 'python-requests/2.31.0', 
        'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate', 
        'Accept': '*/*', 
        'Connection': 'keep-alive', 
        'API-Sign': 'sig1', 
        'api-key': 'key1', 
        'Content-Length': '31', 
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    }
    BODY: 'nonce=1716979150820&trades=True'
    
    
    # HTTPX REQUEST
    HEADERS: {
        'user-agent': 'python-httpx/0.26.0', 
        'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate', 
        'accept': '*/*', 
        'connection': 'keep-alive', 
        'api-sign': 'sig2', 
        'api-key': 'key1', 
        'content-length': '31', 
        'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'host': 'api.kraken.com'
    }
    BODY: b'nonce=1716979150821&trades=true'
 

